# button, jquery and modals

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to understand modals and js better.  I have tried to use buttons that are realated to php files in order to make the content of the php files appear in a modal window once the button is clicked.

so...

button_1 gets file_1 and puts it in modal once it is clicked.
button_2 gets file_2 and puts it in modal once it is clicked.
etc.

I have acheived most of this but for some reason, each button needs to be clicked twice (for the first appearence of the modal window) for the modal to work. Afterwards, a simple click works fine, until the page is refreshed.  At that point, two clicks are again needed.

My code works fine if I don't try to insert the information from the php file into a modal window.  So... I'm guessing it is releated to the fact that the button has to do two things.  1. get the info and 2. open the modal window.

How do I combine both in one click?

I have tried to prefech files.

```
<link rel="prefetch" href="/folders/to/php/files/1.php">
```

I have also tried to pre-insert the modal  in the html .

I have tried to use the load instead of click in the function.

I my tries have not changed the fact that I need to double click the buttons at first.

Any help appreciated!!

<s>BONUS:
If I could get the buttons to dynamically find their related file, that would be bonus. Meaning I could simply add or remove buttons and they would find the correct files. All I would need to do is to add as many files as buttons.</s>

Thanks for your time and help!

Here are the codes:

```js
$("#liste > button").on('click', apar);

function apar() {
  $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
  $('#main_p').load("/folders/to/php/files/" + (1 + $(this).index()) + ".php");

  $(document).ready(function() {
    // Do something with the DOM
    $('.active').click(function() {

    });
  });

}

function renderHTML(data) {


  var htmlP = data.url;

  $('#main_p').html(htmlP);

}

// On page load, click on the first `btn` to automatically load the data for it 
$('#liste > button:first').click(renderHTML);
```

```css
.btn {
  margin: 5px;
  padding 0px 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #0095ff;
  color: #FFF;
  border: none;
}

.btn:hover,
.btn:focus {
  outline: none !important;
  color: #FFF;
}

.active {
  background-color: #891;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title> Modals </title>



  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>





</head>

<body>

  <div id="liste">
    <button class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal_1">
      <div class="tree">to file 1</div>
    </button>
    <button class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal_2">
      <div class="tree">to file 2</div>
    </button>
    <button class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal_3">
      <div class="tree">to file 3</div>
    </button>

    <h4 id="main_tit"></h4>
    <div class="main_p" id="main_p"></div>
    <div id="main_ima"></div>

    <script src="js/main.js" async></script>
</body>

</html>
```

here is the example of a 1.php file:

```
<div id="myModal_1" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Look 1</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <?php

      echo "I have the 1.php <br>";
      echo "its a go!";

     ?>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
```

UPDATE:  I have added the automatic selection on button.  So I have removed the button attributes in the html and have added this at the top of the JS:

```
var idVar = $("#liste").find("button").each(function(index){
$(this).attr("data-target","#myModal_" + (1+$(this).index()));
$(this).attr("data-toggle","modal");
$(this).attr("class","btn");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your js file there is `$("#liste > button").on('click', apar);`

Try to change it to:

```
$('body').on('click', '#liste > button', apar);
```

And put it at the end of your code after your `$('#liste > button:first').click(renderHTML);`

Let me know if this doesn't fix it.

**Edit:** Try creating new custom class for those buttons in HTML. It is good to set a marker to your custom classes, something like l-custom-class, or customClass, try to follow this example:

HTML:

```
<div id="#liste">
    <button type="button" class="l-liste-button">btn1</button>
    <button type="button" class="l-liste-button">btn2</button>
    <button type="button" class="l-liste-button">btn3</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function apar(){
  //some code for apar function..
}
function renderHTML(){
  //some code for renderHTML function
}

$('body').on('click', '.l-liste-button', apar);
$('body').on('click', '.l-liste-button:first', renderHTML);
```

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0mq689ap/)

Comment: Thanks.  I tried it but after the change I still need the double-click at first.

Comment: I think i misunderstood your question. So you need a double-click event listener in order your modal to work? Functions need to run on double-click as well?

Comment: It currently needs a double click but I want it to only need a single click.  Once I have double-clicked all the buttons, a single click works, until I refresh the page, then I need a double-click again.  I want it to be a single click, all the time.  thanks

Comment: Thanks.  Same result.  It works but It needs a double-click at first.  I think (guessing) if there was a way to combine the two lines, it would work, since there would only be one 'click'.  However, when I tried it this way, the link (to the php file) was not correctly getting passed through.  (would always bethe file 0.php)

Comment: You are missing double dots for padding option in your css file for .btn class. Maybe that can cause troubles?

Comment: True! but that doesn't seem to change the functionnality.  It does slightly change the look.  :)  thanks